# Intellij Unresolved Reference for builtin python module (ie. sys)

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

How can I get Intellij to recognizes a builtin that is statically linked to the interpreter such as `sys`?  When I do `import sys` therefore I do not get auto-complete features sys there is no corresponding `.py` file in `site-packages`. And why does this work with PyCharm but it does not work with IntelliJ?

```
import sys

def dump(module):
    if module in sys.builtin_module_names:
        print("<BUILTIN>")
    else:
        module = __import__(module)
        print(module.__file__)

dump("sys")
```

output:

`<BUILTIN>`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue (IntelliJ did not recognise built-in functions like `all`), and found your question.

I was able to solve it myself though: **you have to configure the Python SDK for your IntelliJ project**. This is under File > Project Structure > Facets > Python. If the "Python interpreter" drop-down is empty, you can add one via the "..." button, which opens a "Configure SDKs" dialog.

Usually, this should list **Java SDKs** present on your machine, but you can also add a Python interpreter (or several), using the "+" button. You then navigate to your system's Python interpreter via a file menu (or pick a custom-installed interpreter).

After you have clicked "OK" in the dialog and in the preferences, built-in functions are recognised, and I checked that `sys` functions are auto-completed, too.

I would say this works out of the box for Pycharm because there having at least one Python interpreter declared in the project structure is a requirement, while in Idea with Python as a plugin it is not: having a Java SDK declared is the only requirement for a working project.

Comment: how does adding/configuring a facet differ from just setting Python as the SDK in File > Project Structure > Project? I opened a file individually (intending to save it as a project later) and noticed "tuple" wasn't recognized, and setting the SDK where I just described seemed to work just fine. What does the facet tab even do??

Comment: Thanks for this, took me a number of random pokes and googling to stumble on this correct answer.